# What is the best way to organize code using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating an app, and there is used ui router, all html data append to this tag:

```
 <div class="app" ui-view >
```

But I'd like to include header and footer to my app, and my question is - is it better to use smth like this in index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="top" header></div>
  <div class="app" ui-view >
<div ng-controller="bottom" footer></div>
```

or I should include in every html page two directives - header & footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have each of those things be custom element directives, with their own controllers? That way, you could set it up like this:

```
<ui-header></ui-header>
<ui-view></ui-view>
<ui-footer></ui-footer>
```

This is the "AngularJS way" to do it. It makes the HTML more readable, and also much more concise. Each of those directives will have a template either as a string or in a file that is pointed to during directive creation. That looks something like this:

```
app.directive('uiHeader', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/path/to/template.html',
  };
});
```

The above will place the contents of your template file in the place where you put `<ui-header></ui-header>`. It is also possible to define a controller for each directive, as well as allowing each to have its own scope. You can read more about the creation of custom directives [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 0):

What I usually to is to use an abstract state for the layout which all other states inherits.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('e', {
        abstract: true,
        controller: 'WhateverController',
        templateUrl: 'layout.html',
    })
    .state('e.home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
```

Your layout would look something like this:

```
`<div class="header">
     Some content
</div>
<div ui-view></div>
<div class="footer">
   Footer Content
</div>`
```

Comment: But if you need to add some logic to the footer?

Comment: Probably depends on the size of the logic. You could add it to Whatever controller. Or as above states: using custom directives. I just wanted to show you how I usually use a layout-template for static content with ui-router.